# Jmeter HTTP Request sample and SkipToken

Tags: jmeter

I am using HTTP request sampler for API performance testing. My APIs might return a response containing the  skiptoken
If response contains the skiptoken, I need to call the API again using the skip token and capture the performance metrics. I required calling the API until there are no skiptoken available in the response.
Please let me know how I can implement this in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), for example [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), which will extract the `skpitoken` into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the API response.

If the variable is [defined](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) you can add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) and send another request to the API with the variable from the previous step.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: using JSON Extractor. Not able to extract "@odata.nextLink":"somevalue"  from response.  What should be the JSON Path expression

Answer (score 0):

You have to use any of the **Post processor** according to your API response content. e.g, Json extractor, Regex extractor, Boundary based extractor, whichever suits well.

Then you need to use **While Controller** instead of **If controller**. The While controller it will keep executing the API inside it, until the last skiptoken gets retrieved/ not found - refer the screenshot

[image]

If you use If controller - It will execute only once and proceed with other APIs

Since, I don't know the exact response body structure - you can use Regex to fetch the value, something like the below

```
"@odata.nextLink":"([^ ]+)"
```

[image]